# TYPO3 7.6 bootstrap package - how to change footer height?

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

we are using TYPO3 7.6 bootstrap package and want to change the footer height.

Can you help?

In template - constants we found no option to change this.
[image]

regards
leo

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the output inside your own CSS file. You can include that directly with typoscript

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#includecss-array